MaterialReactTable multi-select filter update based on other filters
I have a table defined as
const [selectOptions, setSelectOptions] = useState([])
const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = useState([])

const table = userMaterialReactTable({
  ...
  columns: [
    ...
    {
      Cell: ({ cell }) => cell.getValue().sort().join(', '),
      ...
      enableColumnFilter: true,
      filterVariant: 'multi-select',
      filterFn(row, id, filterValue) => filterValue.length === 0 || row.getValue(id).some((value) => filterValue.includes(value)),
      filterSelectOptions: selectOptions,
    },
    onColumnFiltersChange: (updater) => {
      setColumnFilters(updater)
      console.log(table.getFilteredRowModel().rows)
    },
    state: {
      columnFilters,
      selectOptions,
      ...
    }
    ...
  ]
  ...
}

The data is of the form
const data = [
  { coumn1: 'value', listColumn: ['a', 'b'], ... },
  { coumn1: 'value', listColumn: ['a'], ... },
  { coumn1: 'value', listColumn: ['b'], ... },
  { coumn1: 'value', listColumn: ['a', 'b', 'a b'], ... },
]

In the useQuery handler that fetches the table data I build a list of filterSelectOptions as [{ label: 'a (3)', value: 'a'}...] but I can't figure out how to get an accurate list of the currently visible rows on filter change so that I can update the selectOptions similar to how the default multi-select filters update.
Using onColumnFiltersChage: setColumnFilters and useEffect(() => {...}, [columnFilters] I can have a reliable event listener for both the initial render and filter changes, but I can't find a way to get enabled filters from the table (doc).
Does anyone know how to get the filter data from the table? Or know of any examples that have a similar implementation?
